# Obrigar a marcar pelo menos 1 checkbox

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma tabela que em cada linha tem duas opções de checkbox, sim e não, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para montar a tabela:

```
$y = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Produto['.$y.']" id= "Produto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Sim['.$y.']">';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Nao['.$y.']">';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <textarea type="text" id="Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
$y++;
}
```

Pretendia obrigar a preencher uma das checkbox em cada uma das linhas e se alguma das linhas não fosse preenchida uma das checkbox mostrar um alerta a avisar que falta preencher uma linha.

Comment: Pq não faz de uma forma mais fácil, somente com um checkbox, se estiver marcado o checkbox, envia sim, se não estiver marcado envia não ?

Comment: descupe aí, essa tabela vai dentro de um form ? porque se for, o html5 ja tem o atributo required. onde você força o preenchimento antes do submit.

Comment: @RiscadoOoOoO e RabisCadoO, não vai dentro de um form, está dentro de uma div.

Comment: @Maikeaerosmith, mas eu pretendo que seja preenchida uma checkbox sendo sim ou não e obrigar o preenchimento de uma delas, porque senão pode haver um esquecimento de preenchimento e até pode existir o produto e regista como não existe.

Comment: @Iniciante a pessoa deve ser capaz de marcar apenas uma opção? Se puder marcar apenas "sim" ou "não", usar `radio button` no lugar de `checkbox` com o atributo required é muito mais fácil e funcional.

Comment: Você pode criar a tabela dentro de uma tag de formulário, e colocar required nos conjuntos de radio button

Comment: a opção mais indicada, é a de nosso amigo @Renan postou.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode alterar o tipo do elemento de [`checkbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) para [`radio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) e incluir o atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required) para torná-lo obrigatório:

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for='sabonete-liquido'>Sabonete Líquido</label>
    <input type='radio' name='sabonete' value='y' required id='sabonete-liquido'>
    <input type='radio' name='sabonete' value='n'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='locao-corporal'>Loção Corporal</label>
    <input type='radio' name='locao-corporal' value='y' required id='locao-corporal'>
    <input type='radio' name='locao-corporal' value='n'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='po-de-talco'>Pó de Talco</label>
    <input type='radio' name='po-de-talco' value='y' required id='po-de-talco'>
    <input type='radio' name='po-de-talco' value='n'>
  </div>

  <!-- ... -->

  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: +1 Boa resposta. Simples e usa o HTML para o que é feito.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @Renan resolve de forma fácil o que se deseja, mas gostaria de acrescentar citando problemas no seu código:

> Antes de mais nada deve-se fazer o que foi sugerido: trocar `checkbox`
>   por `radio`. Você deve usar checkbox apenas quando for de múltipla
>   escolha. Quando só puder escolher 1 opção, deve-se usar radio.

**1. Repetição de id's**

Ao fazer o loop `while` irá repetir o `id= "Produto"` em cada linha, Isso é incorreto pois um id deve ser único. Troque por class: `class= "Produto"`. Está repetindo também outro id: `id="Observacao"`. Troque por `class="Observacao"`.

**2. Nomes e values dos radios**

Opções de `radio` devem ter o mesmo `name`. Você deveria usar o mesmo `name` em cada par de radiobutton de cada linha e atribuir a cada um do par um `value` que irá diferenciar a opção.

Por exemplo, o radio do "sim" pode receber o valor de `s` e o do "não" o valor de `n`, e o `name` pode ser `produto`:

```
<input type="radio" name= "produto['.$y.']" value="s" required>
<input type="radio" name= "produto['.$y.']" value="n">
```

E por fim, falta você fechar os `<td>` da tabela, como, por exemplo, nesta linha:

```
                                                                                   ↓↓↓
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Sim['.$y.']"></td>';
```

Comment: obrigado, já corrigi os erros do meu código e resolvi com a resposta do Renan

Comment: Blz! Se achou a resposta útil, pode votar se quiser. Abs!

Comment: @Iniciante OK!,,